# Strange result on json_encode

Tags: php, android, json

I have the following PHP code:

```
public function remote_login() {
    if($this->isAjax()) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $result = $this->db->prepTemplate("SELECT token, password FROM User WHERE username = ?",'s',array($username), SqlTemplates::RFQ);
        $validate = $this->getSecurity()->validate($password, $result['password'], '5.4');
        if($validate) {
            print json_encode($result['token']);
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

With android I am trying to read the JSON in the following way:

```
public String sendToServer(List<NameValuePair> pair, String url){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if (response != null) {
            InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                try {
                    throw new Exception(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;
            while(true)
            {
                s = buf.readLine();
                if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                    break;
                sb.append(s);

            }
            buf.close();
            ips.close();
            Log.i("Test det her", sb.toString());

            return sb.toString();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

As you can see i log the string result and get the following output:

```
01-21 19:46:51.512    1239-1256/dk.anapp.notebox I/Test det her﹕ [ 01-21 19:46:51.522  1239: 1256 W/dalvikvm ]
```

Which is clearly wrong!

can anyone tell me what is happening? or what i am doing  wrong?

**Console log**

```
    01-21 19:56:59.002    1339-1356/dk.anapp.notebox I/Test det her﹕ [ 01-21 19:56:59.002  1339: 1356 W/dalvikvm ]
    threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a25b90)
01-21 19:56:59.012    1339-1356/dk.anapp.notebox E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: dk.anapp.notebox, PID: 1339
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNull
            at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:191)
            at logic.HTTPReciver.is_auth(HTTPReciver.java:37)
            at dk.anapp.notebox.Mediator.is_auth(Mediator.java:52)
            at dk.anapp.notebox.Login$1.doInBackground(Login.java:45)
            at dk.anapp.notebox.Login$1.doInBackground(Login.java:41)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

** The Url**

"http://notebox.dk/User/remote_login"

**is_auth method**

```
    public Boolean is_auth(String username, String password){
    List<NameValuePair> pair =  new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request","ajax"));
    pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
    pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
    JsonElement root = new JsonParser().parse(sender.sendToServer(pair, "http://notebox.dk/User/remote_login"));
    if(root.getAsString() != null || root.getAsString() != "Error"){
        setToken(root.getAsString());
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the expected result? i have no idea what the token looks like and as far as I'm concerned that's a string you've built

Comment: the token is the following: gTWcn8zs So the result should be: gTWcn8zs

Comment: It seems it's returning nothing, are you sure that $this->isAjax() and $validate are true?

Comment: post your console log exception.

Comment: Those are true else it wouldnt even print anything!

Comment: Please Share the url that you are passing to the method and the code of your Async Class, thanks.

Comment: @SalmanAyub added the url

Comment: This url is throwing `404 not found` error.

Comment: @SalmanAyub Yes it does because  you cannot go to that url unless you use a post and set the variable "request" = "ajax" which i do in the code above

Comment: It seems like, you are returning a String in your Server response and trying to fetch it as JSON Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not a direct answer to you question. But I see that you could simplify your code a lot and maybe so find what is wrong.

First of all, for your webservice, I suggest you to use [Redbean](http://www.redbeanphp.com/). It is a very powerful and simple to use ORM library for PHP.

Then, for making a http query from Android, I always use [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). So you can forget about threading your requests and other details that you'd have to keep in mind without it.

Finally, if you want your life to be easy while parsing json, I strongly recommend you to use the [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.

With these 3 tools, your apps and webservices will work like a charm and your code will look very professional ;)

Comment: But is it correct that i only need to use json_encode ? to make sure that it can actually read the json in android?? or do i need to do something different?

Comment: json_encode should do it. But just to be sure, can you post the webservice response here?

Comment: well the response it reads is: [ 01-21 20:26:38.472  1487: 1501 W/dalvikvm ]

Comment: this does not look like json to me... I mean the server response. Try passing the postdata through your browser with the Postman extension

Comment: it is a browser extension so you can do post request through your browser and see the response

Comment: only that? that is not a json object!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45759/discussion-between-perroloco-and-marc-rasmussen)

Comment: okay can you try for your self: 
request: 'ajax'
username: 'test55@test.dk'
password: 'test'
url = http://notebox.dk/User/remote_login
try this with postman and see what you get!

Answer (score 1):

All examples in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php show that json_encode() takes an array as parameter, not a string. Maybe that's where your problem comes from.

Please try:

```
print json_encode(array("token" => $result['token']));
```

or simply:

```
print json_encode(array($result['token']));
```

If that doesn't work, try to pass a hardcoded string in the json_encode() function and see how it looks in the response in your Android app.